# how to refer auto-wired spring bean inside a serialized java object correctly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, serialization

I have a serialized class which referred non-serialized auto-wired spring-
bean. ( example below )

```
public class DebtorGridAction {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2916970557169315570L;

@Autowired
private DebtorUtility debtorUtility ;
```

When I check my code with Find Bug tool it gives following concern,

> Class com....DebtorGridAction defines non-transient non-serializable instance field debtorGridDataModel

My question is:

Are spring beans already serialized by spring framework? Or should I manually implement the Serializable interface over the spring bean class and serialize the bean class?.

Comment: You shouldn't even attempt to have `DebtorUtility` serialized, since it's an `@Autowired` field. Deserializing such a field would be completely pointless. If you want your `DebtorGridAction` class to be serializable (do you really need it to be?), you need to re-autowire it manually during deserialization.

Comment: No. They're not. I think you're mixing up data and services together and that is not a wise. Separation of concerns. Keep data separate and the services that handle data separate. Most of the time, it's services that will have autowired beans handling data that is serializable.